# JQgrid inline edit second time previously selected row not edit?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I am used `onSelectRow` event for editing selected row.

Initially this event work fine but after editing row, if

1. Refresh grid and
2. Once again try to select previously selected row then it not get editable.

My  `onSelectRow` is:

```
onSelectRow: function(id)
{
  if(id && id!==lastsel)
  {
    jQuery('#My_grid').jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel);
    jQuery('#My_grid').jqGrid('editRow',id,true);
    lastsel=id;
  }
}
```

so please tell me how to fix this problem.

Thank You

Comment: @Alone...posting your code will help..

Comment: so there is my onSelectRow event.

Answer (score 1):

**Can you please try this:**

```
if ($("tr#"+id).attr("editable") == "1") {  // Checking state of grid row
 jQuery('#My_grid').jqGrid('restoreRow',id); 
}
else
{
jQuery('#My_grid').jqGrid('editRow',id,true);
}
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: @Aone..what is the result you are getting? is it not saving or not going to edit mode?

Comment: @alone..its == instead of ===

Comment: all selected row get editable,it not get restore previously selected row after select another row

Comment: @alone..Are you calling the save method..before restoring.

Comment: $("tr#"+id).attr("editable") this return undefined value.is any problem with it?

Comment: @Alone..is it possible for you tp post your entire grid definition?

Answer (score 1):

hey Avinash I solved this issue I am just change in my `onSelectRow` event

```
onSelectRow: function(id)
{
  if(id)
  {
    jQuery('#My_grid').jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel);
    jQuery('#My_grid').jqGrid('editRow',id,true);
    lastsel=id;
  }
}
```

Edit in if condition used `if(id)` instead of `if(id && id!==lastsel)`.